# Python print name of object but only certain part

Tags: python

I want to export a list with all the object in my scene, but i only want it to print a certain part of the name. The name structure is *xxxxxxx_yyyyy_bb-bb.*The X part can differ from 5 to seven digits.

Is there a STOP sign for Python to read up to, so I can say: read until this sign and then stop?

Appreciate the help.

BR Nico

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to print out the xxxxx you can use this:

```
x = name.split("_")[0]
```

so your code could be:

```
import bpy


for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    print(ob.name.split("_")[0])
```

If you have names which do not have the format you described, you should choose this variant:

```
import bpy


for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if len(ob.name.split("_")) > 1:
        print(ob.name.split("_")[1])
    else:
        print("this object does not have the right format:", ob.name)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, and if I want to print the yyyyy part can I use the same technique or does it work different? I'm sorry if the question is trivial, but I'm fairly new to python :)

Comment: just use a 1 instead of 0 for the yyyy part

Comment: When I use 1 instead of 0 I get this error message: IndexError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text.002", line 5, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Comment: Then you have names which aren't in the format you said

Comment: i updated my answer....

Comment: Oh i had an empty in my scene which I didn't see - im sorry for the inconvenience. But I appreciate the help thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions can be very powerful (but the rabbit hole can go pretty deep). Thankfully, the basics are not complicated! Assuming the string is xxxxxxx_yyyyy_bb-bb and you want to get just the yyyyy part, here is a quick sample of how to accomplish this:

```
import re                                   # need to import regular expression module
str = "xxxxxxx_yyyyy_bb-bb"                 # sample string example
match = re.search(r'[a-z]+_([a-z]+)', str)  # match will store each expression found as a list
print(match[1])                             # fetches second expression found
```

The output will be: yyyyy because the second part of the expression found is stored in the second element of the match list. It's been a long while since I touched regex, but like anything else code related, there are many ways to skin a cat so-to-speak, so this is only one possible variant!

Here is the [regular expressions python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

There are plenty of good additional online resources to help get things started. But in the end, learning regex can add a powerful toolkit to your scripting capabilities!

Comment: Hello ! This is interesting, I would just advise against overriding python builtins such as `str` which can have a host of unwanted consequences https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: Hey thanks for the other solution. I will definetly get into the regular expressions, but the other solution fits with what I want to do. But cheers anyways

Comment: @Gorgious - Thanks for the heads up on overriding Python built ins. Duly noted!